# How to do I generate this table in html?

Tags: html, mysql

This is to be generated

[image: This is to be generated]

What I have been able to generate

[image: What I have been able to generate]

I only want help with GUI Part.

```
    <body>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:5%;">
    <h3><b>PRODUCTION</b></h3>
    <table id="StatusTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Phase</th>
            <th>Error Code</th>
            <th>Error Description</th>
            <th>Turnback</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>Incorporation Date</th>
            <th>Completion Date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Authoring</th>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <td>---</td>
            <?php
            session_start();
            $WO_ID = $_SESSION['SELECTED_WO_ID'];
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `associated_wos` WHERE `ID` = '$WO_ID'";
            //echo $sql;
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            { ?>
                <td><?php echo $row["StartDate"]; ?></td>
                <td>---</td>
                <td><?php echo $row["SFCK SubmissionDate"];?></td>
                <?php
            }?>
            ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $value = 'Peer Review';
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `wo_errorinfo` WHERE `WO_NO` = '$WO_ID' AND `Review_Type` = '$value'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            ?>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan = "<?php echo $num_rows + 1 ;?>">Peer Review</th>
            <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
                <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["Error_Code"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["Error_Description"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["Error_Quantity"];?></td>
        <?php
        }?>
            <?php
            $select = "SELECT * FROM `wo_reviewerqa` WHERE `WO_ID` = '$WO_ID' and `reviewType` = '$value'";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$select);
            $num_rows1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
            {?>
                <td rowspan = "<?php echo $num_rows + 1 ?>"><?php echo $row1["reviewScore"];?></td>
                <td rowspan = "<?php echo $num_rows + 1 ?>"><?php echo $row1["reviewStartDate"];?></td>
                <td rowspan = "<?php echo $num_rows + 1 ?>">---</td>
                <td rowspan = "<?php echo $num_rows + 1 ?>"><?php echo $row1["reviewCompleteDate"];?></td>
            <?php
            }
             ?>

     </tr>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

What changes should I make to get the required table. The only way that I have been able to generate that table is if I swap columns. Should I use `JOIN`command?

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: @Jens I have started working on that. The problem is that this project was passed onto me and the developer who was working on this before had not used queries to prevent SQL Injection, due to strict deadline I couldn't wait.

Comment: I upvoted. I understand the frustration of being downvoted when wanting help with something haha

Comment: Thanks @IslamElshobokshy. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You need the GUI, Here is the structure in HTML for your Table

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8"><center>PRODUCTION</center></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phase</td>
        <td>Error Code</td>
        <td>Error Description</td>
        <td>Turnback</td>
        <td>Score</td>
        <td>Start Date</td>
        <td>Incorporation Date</td>
        <td>Completion Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Authoring</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Peer Review</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Internal Review</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Here you are hardcoding the rowspan. That is the issue.

Comment: By hardcoding, you does not mean integrating it into the PHP loops, right? @ritwikshanker

Comment: I want to generate GUI with php Integration. The structure you have given is already generated.(see image of what I have generated)